# Links in annotations no longer linkified on /users/history

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, moderator-tools, annotations

I just noticed that annotations in /users/history/### are no longer linkified in the table of annotations/suspensions at the top of the page. They're linkified everywhere else (like in the annotation entry in the history itself), but not in the table anymore*.

To be clear, I'm talking about things like:

> Linked to http://google.com, that place can't be any good

In the table, the `http://google.com` isn't hyperlinked.

This makes me sad, can it please be fixed?

---

<sup>* I'm 95% sure they used to be, but maybe I'm going insane. Happens to everyone :P</sup>